# C# ListView Select Multiple Items Fires ItemSelectionChanged and SelectedIndexChanged multiple times

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listviewitem

I created a list view where I added rows of data coming from the database.  Imagine there are 200 records in the list view, user selects the first row, then hold shift and click the last row.  This will practically select all 200 rows.  My problem is ItemSelectionChanged  and SelectedIndexChanged  are called 200 times.  I just want my logic to run when everything is finished with selection process.  I can't find solution anywhere so far.

Comment: '*I just want my logic to run when everything is finished with selection process*' → There are several ways for selecting items, it could be programmatically, it could be using keyboard: using arrow, using shift + arrows, using space, using space+arrow+ctrl. it could be using mouse: using click, or using mouse selection rectangle, it could be mouse and keyboard together: using click + shift, or using click + ctrl or there might be other ways as well. Can you define '*when everything is finished with selection process*' for all those cases?

Comment: Maybe you can consider some change on the way that you run some logic on selection changes? For example wait 300 milliseconds after the selection changes, and apply your logic if no new selection?